# scraping a secure page https in php

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

Im trying to crawl a secure page (https) such as [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=crawling%20https#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=site%3astackoverflow.com%20crawling%20https%20php&cp=6&gs_id=s&xhr=t&q=stackoverflow&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=stacko&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8baefeb740f734a5&biw=1280&bih=685) with curl

but I seem to get no data back from my crawler

**php function**

```
function getDOM($url){
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-100');
   $content = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $url."<br>";

   echo $content;


   $dom = new simple_html_dom();
   $dom->load($content);

   if($dom){
      return $dom;
   }

   return null;
}

getDOM("https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=crawling%20https#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=site:stackoverflow.com%20crawling%20https%20php&cp=6&gs_id=s&xhr=t&q=stackoverflow&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=stacko&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8baefeb740f734a5&biw=1280&bih=685");
```

is there anything I can do to crawl a https as I don't seem to have this problem with normal pages

Comment: Can your server's wget can download files over https ?

Comment: Im doing the scraping on my computer using xampp

Comment: try removing `   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-100');`

Comment: try using `CURLOPT_HEADER` and put output here!

Comment: thanks for the comments, google for example does not allow curlopt_range to be implemented

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Add this to your code. This will allow any certificate to pass through, so it should be fine for your use (but not a good idea in general).

Comment: great answer but can you explain why this is not a good idea in general?

Comment: This turns off the verification of SSL certificates. If someone manages to switch IPs with (say) your bank, you will connect to it and be given fake certificate, but your application will accept it. You'll then supply your login to a bad guy